# Angular 9 breaks order of input field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

In Angular 8 I used to do:

```
<tr class="simpleGridRecord" *ngFor="let item of products; let index=index">
      <td [item]="item" [processField]="tableDesc" simpleGridData></td>
</tr>
```

so I would pass into my custom directive named simpleGridData a field (tableDesc) as well as the data via [item] and all worked great.

However in Angular 9 the order of things have changed, now for some reason processField is being called BEFORE [item] and thus I do not have the data I need to work on.

What is the best way to access the ngFor item without passing it in directly as I can no longer count on the order of the passed in value?

Comment: the issue seems like its in how your simpleGridData directive processes data. the order of inputs registering should NOT matter to your directive's implementation. this is basically never guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

so I figured the answer, I had to change the order of the input params, which I thought I did but didn't save properly.
so now in ng 9 I do:

`<td [processField]="tableDesc" [item]="item"/>`

and in ng 8

`<td [item]="item" [processField]="tableDesc"/>`

so ng 9 respects the order of the input fields, must be AOT related.
hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

//abc.html

```
<tr class="simpleGridRecord" *ngFor="let item of products">
<td>{{item}}</td>
```

//abc.ts

```
products: Array<string> =[] // define your data array here
```